# SQL Server 2014 complex Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures

Sorry for the Title but I haven't found a better explanation.

I need to generate a TrackingID number for shipments using data from 3 different tables:

- Sales
- ShippingAddress
- Carriers

I built a query that increments the appropriate `trackingNumber` and returns it together with some extra columns. (In the real query data are stored in a temp table and other queries follow, but now the issue is here.)

Here it is

```
DECLARE @OrderID NVARCHAR(10) = 'B3'

UPDATE cc  
SET NextSeed= IIF(nextSeed IS NULL, NewStartSeed + 1,
                  IIF(nextSeed = LastSeed, NewStartSeed, NextSeed + 1)),
    LastSeed = IIF(NextSeed = LastSeed OR NextSeed IS NULL, NewStopSeed, LastSeed),
    NewStartSeed = IIF(NextSeed = LastSeed OR NextSeed IS NULL, NULL, NewStartSeed),
    NewStopSeed = IIF(NextSeed=LastSeed OR NextSeed IS NULL, NULL, NewStopSeed)
OUTPUT
    COALESCE(deleted.NextSeed, inserted.nextSeed-1) CurrentSeed, 
    inserted.Prefix, inserted.Suffix,
    inserted.ShippingService, inserted.CarrierCode
FROM
    Sales s
JOIN
    ShippingAddress ss ON s.shippingAddressID = ss.ShippingAddressID
JOIN
    Carriers cc ON cc.ShippingService = s.ShippingService 
                AND cc.carriercode = s.carriercode
LEFT JOIN
    SurchargeAreas ssa ON ss.PostalCode = ssa.PostalCode
WHERE
    s.OrderID = @OrderID
```

Now I have to add an extra table that contains, for the different carriers, the PostalCodes with Surcharge:

```
SurchargeAreas Table
```

What I need is:

- if Customer's PostalCode is in SurchargeArea for the selected Carrier I need to change carrier/shippingService to default Carrier/shippingService to avoid extra shipping costs.

I added to the above query the following extra condition:

```
and ssa.postalcode is null
```

That detects if the customer's `postalcode` is in a surcharge area, but returns zero result, and therefore does not select the default shipping service, does not increment the Seed and does not return a result.

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a2ef/1) with all tables and some sample data to better understand.

In the example, the PostalCode of OrderID "B4" is in a surcharge area, while B1, B2 and B3 are not.

Therefore setting

```
@OrderID = 'B1' or 'B2' or 'B3'
```

returns data, while

```
@OrderID = 'B4'
```

does not return anything, while I would expect something like

```
31001     RS    NL   postnlrm    postnl
```

since postnlrm has 'default' column set to 1

Can you suggest how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't return that record when the `CarrierCode` for that `Sales` order is associated with `dhl` and not `postnl`. Are you asking to (at times) ignore the `CarrierCode` relationship between the `Carriers` and `Sales` tables?

Comment: Yes, if the postalcode is in SurchargeArea, it has to override the selected carrier/service and use the default one.

Comment: Are you constrained to one UPDATE? It sounds like you coudld easily do this in two UPDATE statements: one for sales records that are in SurchargeAreas and one for the remainder. You could store your OUTPUT's results by using the frame `OUTPUT
    COALESCE(deleted.NextSeed, inserted.nextSeed-1) CurrentSeed, 
    inserted.Prefix, inserted.Suffix,
    inserted.ShippingService, inserted.CarrierCode INTO @Table...`

Comment: Sorry, not well understood your question:
That above is only part of the query and actually the output goes to a temporary table and then other queries follows.
You mean to execute this query and if result is null to make another query with default parameters?
I already thought about this, and once understood how to check if result is null, probably will work, but was looking for a better solution, if exists (but always exists!)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're essentially asking for the condition of joins to be changed through a lookup ("if my postalcode is in a surcharge area, change my carrier code joins to this, otherwise this"), I would recommend that you split this update into two sets. Here's some pseudocode to help get you started:

```
DECLARE @OrderID nvarchar(10)='B4'
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (CurrentSeed, Prefix, Suffix, ShippingService, CarrierCode)

-- Update Surchargeable Areas with Defaults; this assumes only ONE default for a postal code
UPDATE ...
OUTPUT ... INTO @mytable
FROM Sales                  s
JOIN ShippingAddress            ss  on  s.shippingAddressID=ss.ShippingAddressID
JOIN SurchargeAreas     ssa on  ss.PostalCode=ssa.PostalCode
JOIN dbo.Carriers           cc  on cc.carriercode=ssa.carriercode
      and cc.[Default] = 1  -- terrible practice using a SQL keyword as a column name, by the way!!
WHERE s.OrderID=@OrderID;

-- Update non-Surchargeable Areas
UPDATE ...
OUTPUT ... INTO @mytable
FROM Sales                  s
JOIN ShippingAddress            ss  on  s.shippingAddressID=ss.ShippingAddressID
JOIN Carriers cc ON cc.ShippingService = s.ShippingService 
       AND cc.carriercode = s.carriercode
LEFT JOIN SurchargeAreas        ssa on  ss.PostalCode=ssa.PostalCode
AND cc.[Default] = 0
WHERE s.OrderID=@OrderID
          AND ssa.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: This procedure is for each single shipment: I think is better to
first check if the given postal code is in surcharge area and then according to the result use the 'standard' parameters or override the shipping service: something like `if  not exists (select 1 from Sales s
JOIN ShippingAddress ss ON s.shippingAddressID = ss.ShippingAddressID JOIN Carriers cc ON cc.ShippingService = s.ShippingService AND cc.carriercode = s.carriercode LEFT JOIN SurchargeAreas ssa ON ss.PostalCode = ssa.PostalCode WHERE s.OrderID = @OrderID and ssa.postalcode is null) THEN BEGIN....END ELSE BEGIN... END`

Comment: but I was looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: this is my 'unelegant'  solution: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a2ef/116)

Comment: I've seen more inelegant solutions :) You're certainly welcome to do the check first and and apply control logic to decide which `UPDATE` you want to pursue. I tend to try to use relational sets as best I can instead of specifying control logic, but there could be many factors in one's decision.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Mine is procedural logic, that I do not like when working with SQL, but haven't find a better solution, and I've not understood how to apply your. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Answer (score -3):

Cant you  COALESCE and return default courier  for the area, if courier is NULL or if a surcharge area from the surchargarea table before u join it?

I.e
Left join (select top 1 coaleacse blah from surchargeare) x
On x.postalcode=ss.postalcode.

Sorry if it is not clear, i am not at a desk